# Wrap all exceptions thrown

Tags: scala, exception, traits

I'm designing a trait.

```
trait Storage{
    def write(data: Array[Byte]): Unit
}

class StorageWriteException(t: Throwable) extends RuntimeException(t)
```

How to make all `NonFatal` exceptions thrown by any implementation of `trait Storage` being wrapped into `StorageWriteException`?

Is it possible to do without wrapping it by hand in all the implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define your trait as

```
trait Storage {
  final def write(data: Array[Byte]): Unit = 
    try writeImpl(data) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => throw new StorageWriteException(e)
    }

  protected def writeImpl(data: Array[Byte]): Unit
}
```

And then override `writeImpl` in the implementations instead of `write`. This is a case of the [Template Method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) design pattern